# Google Drive SDK giving access to all users files

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a website that uses the Google Drive SDK to create and save files.  I have the permissions set to only have access to files created by my website.

Today all of the users Google Drive files are now visible from within my website even those not created by my app.  I had a few other users report this to me.

Anyone else seeing this behavior on their website?  Is this a bug or did Google change the behavior of these permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've isolated a Google Drive server issue and have implemented a temporary fix. You should no longer be able to see the issue.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thanks!  It's fixed for me and my users are reporting it fixed too.