# Google Drive not persisting PUT changes

Tags: google-drive-api

To Google:

1) I have an app that uses the Google API JavaScript client. Prior to today, I was able to save changes to an existing user file that's saved on Drive. However, now if I send a PUT request to https://content.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files with updated file contents, I still get a 200 response, but the new file contents are not persisted. (Fetching the file again on page refresh shows the old file state.) None of the app's code has changed since it was last working on Sunday.

I feel this is probably related to [File Revisions suspect behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230205/google-drive-file-revisions-behaviour-suspect) and [Google Drive API file update new possible bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227266/google-drive-api-file-update-new-possible-bug). This should probably be a bug report, but I am unable to find where to submit this to Google as Drive SDK support page says to come to StackOverflow.

**UPDATE**:
There's a thread on the [Google+ site for Google Drive Developers](https://plus.google.com/106160348960403302854/posts/Q7EXHjHiSC5) regarding this issue.

2) Is there a webpage that has information on when Google makes API updates and/or changes that could break functionality? This happened last week: [Google Drive SDK giving access to all users files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144562/google-drive-sdk-giving-access-to-all-users-files) and also affected my app. Is StackOverflow really the best place to learn about these things?

Comment: This is being investigated, should have a fix soon.

Comment: @CherylSimon - looks like things are fixed now. Thanks for your help. Could you please address #2?

Comment: Major changes will be announced in the G+ page.  For bug reports, here or the G+ page are both good places to report issues (depending on if you are sure its a bug, or need an answer.)

Comment: @CherylSimon You might be interested in [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251838/645270).